# enmascarar un input text con javascript para que no muestre en valor

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un campo asi

```
<input class="formclass" name="password" id="password" size="20" maxlength="20" title="password" autocomplete="off" >
```

Pero no puedo usar el tipo password para el input para que se oculte con **** el campo
Quisiera saber de que otra manera por javascript podria ocultarlo sin perder el value  del campo

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar un campo de tipo password? Simular el comportamiento cuando tienes un componente con la funcionalidad necesaria se me hace extraño

Comment: por un tema de una prueba automatizada y me pidieron que lo dejara tipo text pero no puedo dejar la contraseña visible

Comment: Y si la prueba automatizada cambia el tipo del input momentáneamente? Hay formas de hacer lo que quieres, pero realmente crean problemas de seguridad (por ejemplo, tendrías que desactivar el copiar al portapapeles el valor del input)

Answer (score 0):

el `autocomplete = "off"` deberia ir en el `<form>` y no en elementos individuales. Eso deberia funcionarte, ya intentaste?